# Mapping elements to a boolean expression of similar elements

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to solve this problem that I *suspect* might be NP-hard; the basic idea is this:

Given a list of elements $A$, determine if the elements in $A$ can be substituted into a boolean expression that will consist of elements from the same finite alphabet as $A$.

Some constraints on the mapping:

- An element in $A$ can only be mapped to an element in the expression if the two elements are equivalent/equal (for example, $a$ cannot be mapped to anything but $a$)
- Each element in $A$ cannot be mapped to more than one element in the expression
- Mapped elements in the expression are considered "true", and un-mapped elements, false

The goal is to find a generic method/algorithm that tests for if $A$ *can* cause the expression to be evaluated as True

Here's a few examples:
$$ A = {\{b',c'\}}\\ Expression: (a \vee b) \wedge (a \vee b \vee c)$$
In this case, the answer would be true, since you can map it as: $(a \vee b') \wedge (a \vee b \vee c')$

$$ A = \{a\} \\ Expression:  (a \vee b) \wedge (a \vee b \vee c)$$
Here the answer would be false, since there is no single mapping for $a$ that causes the expression to be true.

EDIT:

Thought of another way to describe the problem:

Given a boolean expression, with $k$ different variables, identified as $a_j, b_j, ... $ where $j$ represents the occurrence in the expression. (e.g. $(a_1 \vee b_1) \wedge (a_2 \vee b_2)$)

Find a single value of $j$ for each variable in an input set $A$ (where each variable in $A$ need not exist in the boolean expression) that when $p_j p \in A$ is 1, and all other instances are 0, the boolean expression evaluates to True.